# Publish and subscribe Using Joint_state_publisher for real robot

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, geometry-msgs, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello guys,
I'd like to ask you some question about using joint_state_publisher for real robot. I'm using arm robot and I want to control it using joint_state_publisher. but I have a question :

1. how to visualize and control real robot (especially manipulator) movement by RViz (not moveit)?
2. I still confuse about JointState and can I using it to get Pose (with geometry_msgs)?

thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355302/publish-and-subscribe-using-joint_state_publisher-for-real-robot/) by [DheaSafitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/50598/dheasafitri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which robot/manipulator are you using? Provided that there is a driver available, you need a URDF of your robot to visualize it in RVIZ (http://wiki.ros.org/urdf).

You can use the robot_state_publisher (http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) to track the joint positions of your robot.

For coordinate system transformation, you can use tf2 (http://wiki.ros.org/tf2), which is already available by using the previously mentioned packages. You can get the pose of a specific joint or tcp by looking up the Transformation in tf.

To control the robot through a GUI, you can use the joint_state_publisher_gui package (The joint_state_publisher with the argument use_gui worked for me as well, but it seems to be deprecated now).

Maybe  [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/275079/joint-state-publisher-and-robot-state-publisher/) is helpful for you.

---

Originally posted by [christianlandgraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52949/christianlandgraf/) with karma: 16 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0